# No voltage across this component?

Tags: voltage, kirchhoffs-laws

There is a Problem in our textbook which asks us to find, using Kirchoff's law, the voltage across component v_x and v_y.

According

I know that the voltage at node 1 should be 14 volts from [21 + (-7)]=14 (in terms of $$v=\frac{dw}{dq}$$
not in terms just of potential *difference*.

The voltage across V-x is 9 because the voltage across the two components in series right below it is 5.

Of course, v_y is 14.  This said:

Is there going to be any voltage across the rightmost component?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fboK5Y.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: If you say the voltage at node 1 is 14V, that is most certainly in terms of a potential difference. The implication is that the bottom node in your diagram is ground, which is the assumed point of reference when we speak of a single node having a given voltage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to assume you meant "rightmost" since the leftmost component is a supply.

The voltage across the rightmost component *must* be the same as any components in parallel. Hence, it has 5V across it.

Comment: Ahhhhhh... that absolutely makes sense on the surface of it.  So if Applying Kirchoff's voltage law, every node providing a in parallel counts as only one entry departure from the closed surface?